# How to get rid of the "blocks" message given by cpio?

Tags: shell-script, pipe, io-redirection

I'm trying to look through this: [How do I get the MD5 sum of a directory's contents as one sum?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35832/how-do-i-get-the-md5-sum-of-a-directorys-contents-as-one-sum), and so I'm trying:

```
$ find | LC_ALL=C sort | cpio -o | md5sum
25324 blocks
6631718c8856606639a4c9b1ef24d420  -
```

Hmm... I'd like just the hash, not anything else in the output... so assuming that "25324 blocks" has been printed to stderr, I try to redirect stderr to `/dev/null`:

```
$ find | LC_ALL=C sort | cpio -o | md5sum 2>/dev/null 
25324 blocks
6631718c8856606639a4c9b1ef24d420  -
```

Nope, that's not it. Let's just for tests sake, try to redirect stdout to `/dev/null`:

```
$ find | LC_ALL=C sort | cpio -o | md5sum 1>/dev/null 
25324 blocks
```

Ok, so the hash is gone as expected - but the "blocks" message is still there ?! Where the hell is this "25324 blocks" printed, via file descriptor 3 ?!:

```
$ find | LC_ALL=C sort | cpio -o | md5sum 3>/dev/null 
25324 blocks
6631718c8856606639a4c9b1ef24d420  -
```

Nope, that's not it... In any case, I can get just the hash with awk:

```
$ find | LC_ALL=C sort | cpio -o | md5sum | awk '{print $1}'
25324 blocks
6631718c8856606639a4c9b1ef24d420
```

but still the darn "blocks" message is printed... So how is it printed to terminal at all (as it seems not printed via either stdout or stderr), and how can I suppress that message?

---

EDIT: found the answer, the "blocks" message is printed by `cpio` actually, so the right thing to do is:

```
$ find | LC_ALL=C sort | cpio -o 2>/dev/null | md5sum | awk '{print $1}'
6631718c8856606639a4c9b1ef24d420
```

Now we have just the hash...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The message is printed by `cpio`, this avoids it:

```
find | LC_ALL=C sort | cpio -o 2> /dev/null | md5sum | awk '{print $1}'
```

You’ll lose any error messages printed by `cpio` if you use this approach. Some versions of `cpio` (at least GNU and FreeBSD) support a `quiet` option instead:

```
find | LC_ALL=C sort | cpio -o --quiet | md5sum | awk '{print $1}'
```

To avoid losing errors with a version of `cpio` which doesn’t support `--quiet`, you could log them to a temporary file:

```
cpiolog=$(mktemp); find | LC_ALL=C sort | cpio -o 2> "${cpiolog}" | md5sum | awk '{print $1}'; grep -v blocks "${cpiolog}"; rm -f "${cpiolog}"
```

Answer (score 2):

This message is printed by `cpio`. With GNU cpio or FreeBSD cpio, pass the `--quiet` option to suppress it.

Or ditch cpio and use the standard pax or the more common tar instead.